# Get/Set Line-In Volume in Windows 7 Using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, audio, naudio

I'm looking for a way to get and set the line-in volume in VB.NET.  I was looking at NAudio at first which looked good while capturing audio from the Mic jack, but not so much once I started using the Line In jack (unless I was doing something completely wrong with it).

So now I'm working with CoreAudioApi.dll, but not having any luck on getting the current volume level.  I was only able to find the device "rear blue in", which corresponds with the blue line in jack in the back.

Does anyone have any tips on what my next step(s) should be?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim enmDevice As New MMDeviceEnumerator
    Dim devDevice As MMDeviceCollection = enmDevice.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(EDataFlow.eAll, EDeviceState.DEVICE_STATEMASK_ALL)
    Dim intLineIn As Int32 = -1

    For i As Int32 = 0 To devDevice.Count - 1

        If devDevice.Item(i).FriendlyName = "Rear Blue In" Then
            intLineIn = i
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    If intLineIn = -1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim devLineIn As MMDevice = devDevice.Item(intLineIn)

    MessageBox.Show(devLineIn.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel)
    MessageBox.Show(devLineIn.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar)
    MessageBox.Show(devLineIn.AudioEndpointVolume.VolumeRange.MindB)
    MessageBox.Show(devLineIn.AudioEndpointVolume.VolumeRange.MaxdB)
    MessageBox.Show(devLineIn.AudioEndpointVolume.VolumeRange.IncrementdB)

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'next steps'??  Does the code above work for you?  (I don't have time to play with it at the moment).  Is your question how to write to the volume levels?

Comment: This code works, but it doesn't get the volume level of the device, which is what I'm trying to do.  I'd be looking for something like this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370920(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11695/Audio-Library-Part-I-Windows-Mixer-Control

Comment: What's with the `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: I believe that would be the early nineties @DouglasBarbin :D

Comment: @Plutonix: That article is from 2006.  I've got code (somewhere) that works fine on XP using those methods.  However, it's very different in Windows 7.  I'm not in a position to criticise one way or the other, because never got around to getting it to work in 7, but I'm just pointing out the OP might have a host of different problems using the old APIs.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin, I put that in there because this is test code and I didn't care about catching errors (I was running into one early on).

Comment: @Plutonix I'll check that article out tomorrow, I didn't see that particular one when I was looking earlier.

Comment: @Grim Yeah, it's like you said.  I tried the Mixer project in Win 7 and the sliders seemed to have no effect on anything.

Comment: It looks like this will actually work for me.  I just need to mute the Line In volume in the RealTek control panel, and turn on "Listen to this device" under Windows Control Panel -> Sound -> Recording -> Line In -> Listen -> "Listen to this device".